# Does react native refesh control work on android?

Tags: android, facebook, react-native

I have React Native Refresh control working on IOS.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/refreshcontrol.html

I run it on the android sim and it does not work.

Error says Unhandled Promise Rejection.

Here is trimmed version of the file so you can see the set up:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  RefreshControl,
} from 'react-native';

export default class Products extends Component {
  _onRefresh() {
    this.setState({refreshing: true});
    this.likedProducts()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView
          contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollContent}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          refreshControl={
            <RefreshControl
              refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
              onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
            />
          }
        >
        ...
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is supported to use a ScrollView with RefreshControl on Android.  I would recommend to use https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html instead. There you have pull-to-refresh natively integrated on both Android & iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that it does work for android and ios. The error i received was from somewhere else.